# Django initial_data.json memory issues

Tags: django

I have a huge (400MB) initial_data.json file.  Django's eating up all my memory trying to load this file.

Suggestions?  Surely someone out there has large initial_data files they use.  I'd consider converting this into an xml file, but I don't know if Django will try to load all that into memory as well, and I'm not yet ready to try it out without being sure.

Comment: Can you explain why you would use json for such a large amount of data? This seems to be a situation where an SQL dump (or CSV per table) would be a much better solution.

Comment: You could also make fixture per model and custom management command which loads one by one... but some kind of SQL dump as WoLpH suggested is a way to go for such a large data set.

Comment: I would like it to be database independent, but I have been considering going the csv + custom management command route.  I'm going to try Seth's response and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a json file, django routes it through simplejson, which eventually does this:

```
    return loads(fp.read(),  ...)
```

*(From django.utils.simplejson)*

In other words, the entire file is read (`fp.read()`) before it's passed on to the decoder. It seems possible (but not trivial) to modify simplejson to read file a bit at a time.

However, the XML serializer uses [pulldom](http://www.prescod.net/python/pulldom.html), which apparently "streams" the XML file. As such, it should be much more memory efficient.

Comment: Sounds good.  I'm going to try it out and if it works I'll mark this answer.